# Objective-C - Wrong data binding?

Tags: objective-c

I wonder if there is anything wrong in this code:

```
//MyViewController.h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *aLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myString;

@end

//MyViewController.m
@implementation MyViewController

-(void)setMyString:(NSString *)myString{
    if (_myString != myString) {
        _myString = myString;
        self.myLabel.text = myString;
    }
}

@end
```

Regards!

Comment: Is there any reason for a negative vote? As I can see in the answers, the way I'm comparing the strings are wrong, thats fine, but my point is: is it wrong to set self.myLabel.text in the setter of myString?

Answer (score 2):

you need

```
![_myString isEqualToString: myString];
```

instead of

```
_myString != myString
```

PS:
also use 
    self->_myString

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that you are using

```
self.myString = @"new String"
```

instead of

```
_myString = @"new String"
```

self.property is equal to [self setProperty]